# How to handle PHP session management using Datatable JS

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, datatable, datatables

I am struggling with below issue since a long time.
Here are the required details.
**Language** : PHP
**Framework** : Codeignitor
**Library** : Datatable.js (client side)

**Issue:** For the Admin panel, we have used Datatable.js to list respected records. So I am getting following error (attached Image) when few pages are still opened while session has been expired.
**NOTE**: If I refresh the page then it will redirect to my admin login page but I need the solution without refreshing page.
[image]

I hope the explanation will help to sort out an issue. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Why even use sessions with AJAX? To me it seems just to be an blocking overhead.

Comment: @davidkonrad are implying an admin panel shouldn't use ajax? because admin = logged in = sessions

Comment: @Alex No, just avoid sessions in the scripts. I cannot see the benefit of a  `start_session()` in an AJAX script that delivers content you would have to close anyway to prevent blocking. You have access to referrers, you can add tickets to the requests, you could prevent cross domain access etc instead.

Comment: @davidkonrad i have a button that publishes a post. its only available in the authenticated section of my site. for user experience it does this via ajax. how could i do this via ajax if i didn't have an authenticated session? the script would be wide open, or i'd have to do it with redirects and flash messages. I really don't get your point unless this is an open api.

Comment: @Alex, by not base authentification in ajax script on sessions. I have had the samme issue multiple times, only using PHP as a server backend that delivers JSON (logged in or not logged in) it is simply too slow to use sessions, and you'll see unexpected problems like OP's session timeout. Sessions is great for old style PHP layout where your server generate pages and have a session cookie and can maintain variables across pages, not so effective in for example a single page environment, not for me at least.

Comment: @davidkonrad what do you use instead of sessions (curious not debating)? how would you handle something that requires authentication? and i would argue that if you have a single page environment you always expect some sort of ajax response and thus, when you ping the server to do x and the session is invalid (as that would be the first thing to check in an authenticated app by your controller) you just serve out an error. of course im simplifying, but chances are if youre using ci your not fully single-paged, and sessions are the best options.

Comment: @Alex, I have different sort of checks to ensure outside / illegal access, like a mechanical cleansing. Then I let the server script pass back a ticket to the client, and requests is only valid with that ticket. It is basically "sessions" without sessions, you can maintain tickets in a file. If a user not is logged in certain elements are not rendered, and if a "session" timeouts a cooikie is just updated clientside (so I can have "remember me"). Perhaps it is a stupid approach, but at least I can avoid the blocking and starting and closing sessions over and over.

Answer (score 0):

What I suspect is happening is when you are on the page and the session expires and the user requests something with Ajax, the page requested redirects to the login page. Thus, if you look at your network traffic and the requested action you will see the page getting served is the redirected page and not a valid Json response hence your error.

I have a similar thing on my site. Basically every page that requires a user to be logged in is protected by a function that checks to see if the user is logged in and able to view the page. If not, either one of two things happen, the user gets redirected OR if the request type is Ajax, than I parse a Json error.

I suggest you adopt something similar to what I outlined. Just note, it is important for continuity that you use the same response format both in php and in parsing your Ajax errors throughout your php and js scripts.

Example:

```
public function protect($allowed = array())
{
    $uri = uri_string();
    // user isn't logged in
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()) {
        if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
            encode_response('error', $this->lang->line('login_expired'));
        } elseif ($uri == rtrim($this->success_login_redirect, '/')) {
            redirect(CMS_DIR_NAME . '/login');
        } else {
            $this->session->set_userdata('login_redirect', '/' . $uri);
            redirect(CMS_DIR_NAME . '/login');
        }
    }
    $this->session->unset_userdata('login_redirect');
    if (!$this->ion_auth->is_admin() && !$this->ion_auth->in_group($allowed, $this->curr_user->id())) {
        if (!$this->is_user_allowed($this->curr_user->group()->name)) {
            show_error($this->lang->line('messages_page_access'), 403, 'Error');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @alex
So your suggestion is to parse specific message from Ajax call and based on that I need to redirect to login page using PHP script. Is that so?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example. Basically protect() is called in the __construct() of every controller I have. Any ajax requests after the session expires creates and json_encoded error. In my js I simply check to see if an error exists and if so parse the error message and in your case, avoid rendering the datatable? Is that clearer? Of course you could call a specific error 'session_expired' and refresh the page in js based on that, but I do it this way because all my js functions that use ajax read encode_response and just display an error.